P50 has bluetooth error on ubuntu 22.04: Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to send firmware data (-38)
i installed ubuntu 22.04 new on my old lenovo P50. and now the bluetooth isnt working anymore. before the installation it was working.
dmesg gives me:
$ dmesg | grep Blue
[    6.764460] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    6.764780] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    6.764784] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    6.764787] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    6.764793] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    6.836449] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 2 week 52 2014
[    6.840894] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 5
[    6.840898] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[    6.840899] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[    6.840901] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[    6.840910] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[    6.840911] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[    6.844843] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-11-5.sfi
[    7.087607] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to send firmware data (-38)
[    7.087730] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel reset sent to retry FW download
[    9.278508] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0xfca6 tx timeout
[    9.278589] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading supported features failed (-110)
[    9.278593] Bluetooth: hci0: Error reading debug features
[    9.278596] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI LE Coded PHY feature bit is set, but its usage is not supported.
[   10.306425] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   10.306429] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   10.306434] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized

what could it be? where to search?
thanks a lot

Needs details when was it working? A previous version of Ubuntu? Please edit the question and add this info

my system is:
System:
Kernel: 6.8.0-40-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A Desktop: Cinnamon 6.0.4 tk: GTK 3.24.33
wm: muffin vt: 7 dm: LightDM 1.30.0 Distro: Linux Mint 21.3 Virginia base: Ubuntu 22.04 jammy
before i had some other version, based on 20.04...
but the strange thing is, that the install USB-stick works with BT. and after booting with the install USB stick, the real system works also....
the log of a normal start and the usb-stick start:
but how can i attach it?

Mint is not Ubuntu and is off topic on this Ubuntu only support site.
